# Debugging raw view content

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging

When inspecting an object in debug mode, there is sometimes, if not always, a Raw View that can be expanded. What is this? Can I access this in my code?

Comment: What specifically are you asking about?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For some complex types, such as `List` or `List<T>`, the VS devs have developed a customized view (Debugger Proxy) that makes viewing the object easier/clearer and provides a more helpful display.  You can create your own customized views if you want to.

The Raw view is the raw object, without anything else added (or removed).

I don't see why you'd want to access the debug view in your code, as you already have access to the object in your code.  Unless of course you're talking about accessing the private/protected properties you see in debug view but don't have access to in code. You can access these, via reflection.

Answer (score 4):

This is a [debugger type proxy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d8eyd8zc.aspx).
`Raw View` shows you the ordinary members of the object—what you would have seen had there not been a `DebuggerTypeProxy`.